# AddEventListener not working for InAppBrowser - IONIC 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm trying  to  implement **AddeventListener**  to  listen  'Exit' and 'LoadStart' for InAppBrowser in IONIC2

my html

```
<button (click)="browsersystem('https://www.google.com')" > URL</button>
```

mt.TS file

```
 browsersystem(url:string)
{
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        let browser=open(url, "_system", "location=true"); 
        browser.addEventListener('exit',()=>
        {
          console.log('Browser Closed');
          alert('Browser Closed');

        })

        browser.addEventListener('loadstart',()=>
        {
console.log('Browser STARTED');

        })
        });

}
```

No  errors  on  console.

Is  there  something  am i missing ??

Comment: Is the browser opening at all ? If it is not than I have a solution to your problem.. from this it seems it does not..

Answer (score 1):

```
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';

...

let browser=InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=true"); 
browser.addEventListener('exit',()=>
{
  console.log('Browser Closed');
  alert('Browser Closed');
});
```

This is not at all how it's documented / how it should work, but as the code currently stands, this is what works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, see below :

```
this.platform.ready().then(success => {
      let browser = new InAppBrowser(url, '_system');
      browser.on('exit').subscribe(
            () => {
              console.log('done');
            },
      err => console.error(err));
      });
```